# Optimize number for SQL queries

Tags: java, spring

I use this code to to generate chart with data:

```
    @GetMapping("/terminals")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, List<TopTerminalsDTO>>> getTopTerminals(
            @RequestParam(value = "start_date", required = true) String start_date,
            @RequestParam(value = "end_date", required = true) String end_date) {


        final List<PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts> list = dashboardService.findTop_Terminals(start_dateTime, end_dateTime);

        final Collector<PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts, List<TopTerminalsDTO>, List<TopTerminalsDTO>> terminalsCollector = Collector
                .of(ArrayList::new, (terminals, p) -> terminals.add(mapper.toTopTerminalsDTO(p)),
                        (accumulator, terminals) -> {
                            accumulator.addAll(terminals);
                            return accumulator;
                        });

        final Map<String, List<TopTerminalsDTO>> final_map = list.stream().filter(p -> p.getTerminal_id() != null)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> getTerminalName(p.getTerminal_id()), terminalsCollector));

        return ResponseEntity.ok(final_map);
    }

    private String getTerminalName(Integer id) {      
        Optional<Terminals> obj = terminalService.findById(id);       
        return obj.map(Terminals::getName).orElse("");
    }
```

But I noticed that `getTerminalName` is called more than 10 times to translate the name from number. Do you know how I can reduce the number of calls with some optimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a case for a temporary cache, scoped to just this request, or perhaps longer if the terminal names are stable enough.

Clearly something like ehCache behind the scenes would suit this well, but I am often tempted with a tactical bit of caching, especially if I don't want to keep the cached values beyond this immediate request.

For example:

```
    TerminalNameCache cache = new TerminalNameCache();

    final Map<String, List<TopTerminalsDTO>> final_map = list.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getTerminal_id() != null)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    p -> cache.getTerminalName(p.getTerminal_id()),
                    terminalsCollector));
```

Then the `TerminalNameCache` is just an inner class in the parent Controller class.  This is to allow it to call the existing `private String getTerminalName(Integer id)` method from the question (shown as on `ParentControllerClass` below):

```
private class TerminalNameCache {
    private final Map<Integer, String> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private String getTerminalName(Integer id) {
        return cache.computeIfAbsent(id,
                id2 -> ParentControllerClass.this.getTerminalName(id2));
    }
}
```

---

If this looks like emerging into a pattern, it would be worth refactoring the caching to something more re-useable.  E.g. this could based around caching calls to a generic function:

```
public class CachedFunction<T, R> implements Function<T, R> {
    private final Function<T, R> function;
    private final Map<T, R> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public CachedFunction(Function<T, R> function) {
        this.function = function;
    }

    @Override
    public R apply(T t) {
        return cache.computeIfAbsent(t, t2 -> function.apply(t2));
    }
}
```

This would then be used like this:

```
    CachedFunction<Integer, String> cachedFunction = new CachedFunction<>(
            id -> getTerminalName(id));

    final Map<String, List<TopTerminalsDTO>> final_map = list.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getTerminal_id() != null)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    p -> cachedFunction.apply(p.getTerminal_id()),
                    terminalsCollector));
```

Comment: Very good answer. I will test it. Just in case are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Modify `findTop_Terminals` and `PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts` to include the name (using a SQL `LEFT JOIN` clause).

---

Alternative, scan the list for all terminal ids, then call a `List<Terminals> list = terminalService.findByIds(idList);` method to get all those terminals using a SQL `IN` clause.

*Note: Beware limit on how many `?` markers can be in a SQL statement.*

Then build a `Map<Integer, String>` mapping terminal id to name, and replace `getTerminalName` method with map lookup.

Comment: I know but I would like to make the translation into the Java code.

Comment: @PeterPenzov No. I don't know what technology you use in your Service / DAO layer, so how could I possible show you an example. If you need help with that, ask a *new* question and include the relevant information. *This* question has been answered!!

Comment: @Peter Penzov; if you show us your stored procedures, people may be able to help you with the code change. I think that would be the best solution to your problem. Another solution that is "safer" to implement, would be to create a new stored procedure that returns all the information you want.